# SAML remote Discovery service : missing "return" parameter

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I'm using Spring Security SAML 1.0.1. I've [set up the IDP metadata so it reaches a Discovery service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741388/how-to-configure-the-remote-discovery-with-spring-security-saml) which is defined by `idpDiscoveryURL`. This parameter contains the URL `http://wayf-shib.ueb.eu/fede-renater/WAYF`.

The remote Discovery is reached, but it complains that the request does not contain the "return" parameter. Indeed, this is the request that Spring SAML generates:

```
http://wayf-shib.ueb.eu/fede-renater/WAYF?entityID=http%3A%2F%2Facem.u-bretagneloire.fr%3A80%2FACEM%2Fsaml%2Fmetadata&returnIDParam=idp
```

The generated parameters are :

- `entityID` with the correct value;
- `returnIDParam` with the value "idp" that is set automatically by Spring SAML.

**Question** : How I can configure Spring Security SAML so that it generates a `return` parameter in the request?

---

If this can help, this is my current configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<b:beans xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- Enable auto-wiring -->
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- Scan for auto-wiring classes in spring saml packages -->
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security.saml"/>

<!-- Security for the administration UI -->
<http pattern="/saml/web/**" use-expressions="false">
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/saml/web/metadata/login"/>
    <form-login login-processing-url="/saml/web/login" login-page="/saml/web/metadata/login" default-target-url="/saml/web/metadata"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/metadata/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
</http>

<!-- Secured pages with SAML as entry point -->
<http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint"  use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <!-- For Spring Security 4.x, we need to disable csrf, otherwise AJAX requests get 403:-->
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
    <intercept-url access="permitAll" pattern="/" /><!-- To permit "/" allows the use of web.xml's <welcome-file> -->
    <intercept-url access="permitAll" pattern="/home" />
    <intercept-url access="permitAll" pattern="/pages/exceptions/**" />
    <intercept-url access="permitAll" pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" />
    <intercept-url access="permitAll" pattern="/resources/**" />
    <intercept-url access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" pattern="/administration/**" />
    <intercept-url access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" pattern="/rest/**" />
    <intercept-url access="isAuthenticated()" pattern="/**"/><!-- When the user is authentificated by the IDP, but doesn't exist in the application database -->
    <form-login login-page="/login" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/home"/>
    <custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
    <custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
</http>

<!-- Filters for processing of SAML messages -->
<b:bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
        <filter-chain pattern="/saml/login/**" filters="samlEntryPoint"/>
        <filter-chain pattern="/saml/logout/**" filters="samlLogoutFilter"/>
        <filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**" filters="metadataDisplayFilter"/>
        <filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSO/**" filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>
        <filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSOHoK/**" filters="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"/>
        <filter-chain pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**" filters="samlLogoutProcessingFilter"/>
        <filter-chain pattern="/saml/discovery/**" filters="samlIDPDiscovery"/>
    </filter-chain-map>
</b:bean>

<!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login -->
<b:bean id="successRedirectHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <b:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/"/>
    <b:property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true"/>
</b:bean>

<!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login -->
<b:bean id="failureRedirectHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <b:property name="useForward" value="true"/>
    <b:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/error.jsp"/>
</b:bean>

<!-- Handler for successful logout -->
<b:bean id="successLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
    <b:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/logout.jsp"/>
</b:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <!-- Register authentication manager for SAML provider -->
    <authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider"/>
    <!-- Register authentication manager for administration UI -->
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service id="adminInterfaceService">
            <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<!-- Logger for SAML messages and events -->
<b:bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger"/>

<!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
<b:bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
    <b:constructor-arg value="classpath:security/samlKeystore.jks"/>
    <b:constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="nalle123"/>
    <b:constructor-arg>
        <b:map>
            <b:entry key="apollo" value="nalle123"/>
        </b:map>
    </b:constructor-arg>
    <b:constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="apollo"/>
</b:bean>

<!-- Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from properties file -->
<b:bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
    <b:property name="defaultProfileOptions">
        <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
            <b:property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
        </b:bean>
    </b:property>
</b:bean>

<!-- IDP Discovery Service -->
<b:bean id="samlIDPDiscovery" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery">
    <b:property name="idpSelectionPath" value="/WEB-INF/security/idpSelection.jsp"/>
</b:bean>

<!-- Filter automatically generates default SP metadata -->
<b:bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <b:constructor-arg>
        <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
            <b:property name="entityId" value="http://acem.u-bretagneloire.fr:80/ACEM"/>
            <b:property name="entityBaseURL" value="http://acem.u-bretagneloire.fr:80/ACEM"/>
            <!-- POSSIBLY IMPORTANT, OTHERWISE THE USER MIGHT BE REFERENCED BY THE NameID VALUE
                 (example: _246558c0d7c514447292d750df577b6b) AND NOT THE USERDETAILS "LOGIN" VALUE
                 Note : I haven't tested to remove this property and see if it still works. -->
            <b:property name="nameID" value="PERSISTENT" />
            <b:property name="includeDiscoveryExtension" value="true"/>
            <b:property name="extendedMetadata">
                <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    <b:property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="true"/>
                    <b:property name="idpDiscoveryURL" value="http://wayf-shib.ueb.eu/fede-renater/WAYF"/>
                    <b:property name="idpDiscoveryResponseURL" value="http://acem.u-bretagneloire.fr/ACEM/saml/login/alias/defaultAlias?disco=true&amp;return=http%3A%2F%2acem.u-bretagneloire.fr/ACEM/"/>
                </b:bean>
            </b:property>
        </b:bean>
    </b:constructor-arg>
</b:bean>

<!-- The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix and presents SP metadata there -->
<b:bean id="metadataDisplayFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter"/>

<!-- Configure HTTP Client to accept certificates from the keystore for HTTPS verification -->
<!--
<b:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolConfigurer">
    <b:property name="sslHostnameVerification" value="default"/>
</b:bean>
-->

<!-- IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of 
    trust is here -->
<b:bean id="metadata"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <b:constructor-arg>
        <b:list>
            <b:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <b:constructor-arg>
                    <b:bean
                        class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
                        <!-- URL containing the metadata -->
                        <b:constructor-arg>
                            <b:value type="java.lang.String">https://federation.renater.fr/test/renater-test-metadata.xml</b:value>
                        </b:constructor-arg>
                        <!-- Timeout for metadata loading in ms -->
                        <b:constructor-arg>
                            <b:value type="int">15000</b:value>
                        </b:constructor-arg>
                        <b:property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool" />
                    </b:bean>
                </b:constructor-arg>
                <b:constructor-arg>
                    <!-- Default extended metadata for entities not specified in the map -->
                    <b:bean
                        class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                        <b:property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="true"/>
                        <b:property name="idpDiscoveryURL" value="http://wayf-shib.ueb.eu/fede-renater/WAYF"/>
                        <b:property name="idpDiscoveryResponseURL" value="http://acem.u-bretagneloire.fr/ACEM/saml/login/alias/defaultAlias?disco=true&amp;return=http%3A%2F%2acem.u-bretagneloire.fr/ACEM/"/>
                    </b:bean>
                </b:constructor-arg>
                <b:constructor-arg>
                    <!-- Extended metadata for specific IDPs -->
                    <b:map>
                        <b:entry key="http://idp.ssocircle.com">
                            <b:bean
                                class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata" />
                        </b:entry>
                    </b:map>
                </b:constructor-arg>
            </b:bean>
        </b:list>
    </b:constructor-arg>
    <!-- OPTIONAL used when one of the metadata files contains information 
        about this service provider -->
    <b:property name="hostedSPName" value="http://acem.u-bretagneloire.fr:80/ACEM/saml/metadata"/>
    <!-- OPTIONAL property: can tell the system which IDP should be used for 
        authenticating user by default. -->
    <b:property name="defaultIDP" value="https://ident-shib-test.univ-rennes1.fr/idp/shibboleth"/>
</b:bean>

<!-- SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML messages -->
<b:bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">
    <!-- OPTIONAL property: can be used to store/load user data after login -->
    <b:property name="userDetails">
        <b:bean class="eu.ueb.acem.services.auth.SamlAuthenticationUserDetailsService"/>
    </b:property>
    <!-- VERY IMPORTANT, OTHERWISE THE USER WILL BE REFERENCED BY THE NameID VALUE
         (example: _246558c0d7c514447292d750df577b6b) AND NOT THE USERDETAILS "LOGIN" VALUE -->
    <b:property name="forcePrincipalAsString" value="false"/>
</b:bean>

<!-- Provider of default SAML Context -->
<b:bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl"/>

<!-- Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages -->
<b:bean id="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter">
    <b:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <b:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
    <b:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
</b:bean>

<!-- Processing filter for WebSSO Holder-of-Key profile -->
<b:bean id="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter">
    <b:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <b:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
    <b:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
</b:bean>

<!-- Logout handler terminating local session -->
<b:bean id="logoutHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
    <b:property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="false"/>
</b:bean>

<!-- Override default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML messages -->
<b:bean id="samlLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter">
    <b:constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
    <b:constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    <b:constructor-arg index="2" ref="logoutHandler"/>
</b:bean>

<!-- Filter processing incoming logout messages -->
<!-- First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful global logout -->
<b:bean id="samlLogoutProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter">
    <b:constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
    <b:constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
</b:bean>

<!-- Class loading incoming SAML messages from httpRequest stream -->
<b:bean id="processor" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
    <b:constructor-arg>
        <b:list>
            <b:ref bean="redirectBinding"/>
            <b:ref bean="postBinding"/>
            <b:ref bean="artifactBinding"/>
            <b:ref bean="soapBinding"/>
            <b:ref bean="paosBinding"/>
        </b:list>
    </b:constructor-arg>
</b:bean>

<!-- SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
<b:bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
<b:bean id="hokWebSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile -->
<b:bean id="webSSOprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile -->
<b:bean id="hokWebSSOProfile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 ECP profile -->
<b:bean id="ecpprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileECPImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Logout Profile -->
<b:bean id="logoutprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl"/>

<!-- Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages -->
<b:bean id="postBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding">
    <b:constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    <b:constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
</b:bean>

<b:bean id="redirectBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding">
    <b:constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</b:bean>

<b:bean id="artifactBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPArtifactBinding">
    <b:constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    <b:constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
    <b:constructor-arg>
        <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl">
            <b:constructor-arg>
                <b:bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
                    <b:constructor-arg>
                        <b:bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager"/>
                    </b:constructor-arg>
                </b:bean>
            </b:constructor-arg>
            <b:property name="processor">
                <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
                    <b:constructor-arg ref="soapBinding"/>
                </b:bean>
            </b:property>
        </b:bean>
    </b:constructor-arg>
</b:bean>

<b:bean id="soapBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPSOAP11Binding">
    <b:constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</b:bean>

<b:bean id="paosBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPAOS11Binding">
    <b:constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</b:bean>

<!-- Initialization of OpenSAML library-->
<b:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap"/>

<!-- Initialization of the velocity engine -->
<b:bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory" factory-method="getEngine"/>

<!-- XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing -->
<b:bean id="parserPool" class="org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool" init-method="initialize">
    <b:property name="builderFeatures">
        <b:map>
            <b:entry key="http://apache.org/xml/features/dom/defer-node-expansion" value="false"/>
        </b:map>
    </b:property>
</b:bean>

<b:bean id="parserPoolHolder" class="org.springframework.security.saml.parser.ParserPoolHolder"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! The `return` parameter must be passed using the query string of `idpDiscoveryURL` in encoded form.

While this sounds obvious, this is really not when we read the documentation (where nothing is said about this parameter at all).

And because most of the configuration of Spring SAML is done with `<property name="..." value="..." />` tags, it took me two weeks to configure this stuff correctly.

My configuration of bean `metadata` now looks like this:

```xml
<!-- IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of 
    trust is here -->
<b:bean id="metadata"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <b:constructor-arg>
        <b:list>
            <b:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <b:constructor-arg>
                    <b:bean
                        class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
                        <!-- URL containing the metadata -->
                        <b:constructor-arg>
                            <b:value type="java.lang.String">https://federation.renater.fr/test/renater-test-metadata.xml</b:value>
                        </b:constructor-arg>
                        <!-- Timeout for metadata loading in ms -->
                        <b:constructor-arg>
                            <b:value type="int">15000</b:value>
                        </b:constructor-arg>
                        <b:property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool" />
                    </b:bean>
                </b:constructor-arg>
                <b:constructor-arg>
                    <!-- Default extended metadata for entities not specified in the map -->
                    <b:bean
                        class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                        <b:property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="true"/>
                        <b:property name="idpDiscoveryURL" value="https://wayf-test.ueb.eu/fede-renater-ueb-test/WAYF?return=http%3A%2F%2Facem.u-bretagneloire.fr%2FACEM%2Fsaml%2Flogin"/>
                        <!-- 
                        <b:property name="idpDiscoveryURL" value="https://discovery.renater.fr/test?entityId=http%3A%2F%2Facem.u-bretagneloire.fr%3A80%2FACEM%2Fsaml%2Fmetadata&amp;return=http%3A%2F%2Facem.u-bretagneloire.fr%2FACEM%2Fsaml%2Flogin"/>
                        -->
                        <b:property name="idpDiscoveryResponseURL" value="http://acem.u-bretagneloire.fr/ACEM/saml/login/alias/defaultAlias?disco=true"/>
                    </b:bean>
                </b:constructor-arg>
                <b:constructor-arg>
                    <!-- Extended metadata for specific IDPs -->
                    <b:map>
                        <b:entry key="http://idp.ssocircle.com">
                            <b:bean
                                class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata" />
                        </b:entry>
                    </b:map>
                </b:constructor-arg>
            </b:bean>
        </b:list>
    </b:constructor-arg>
    <!-- OPTIONAL used when one of the metadata files contains information 
        about this service provider -->
    <b:property name="hostedSPName" value="http://acem.u-bretagneloire.fr:80/ACEM/saml/metadata"/>
    <!-- OPTIONAL property: can tell the system which IDP should be used for 
        authenticating user by default. -->
    <b:property name="defaultIDP" value="https://ident-shib-test.univ-rennes1.fr/idp/shibboleth"/>
</b:bean>
```